# A simple question about POST and GET request

Tags: python, django, request

I just started to learn Django by following a sentdex tutorial. During the course, we added a User model into our database and we created a function in our views.py file:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():#si les champs sont OK : 
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else: 
            for msg in form.error_messages: 
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
```

But in this piece of code, I don't understand how Django knows if the request.method is True or False. Is it because I created a form with a Submit button in my template ?

Comment: It doesn't check whether the method is true or false, it checks whether it's POST or not. It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Django takes the raw HTTP request, breaks it into various variables and manages which function to invoke based on routing etc. `request.method` is set as part of this process and will equal `"POST"` if the request was a HTTP POST.

Comment: In this line `if request.method == "POST"`, that means your request.method is checking if it a post request or not. So when you submit a form, on the top of the form tag you have mentioned method='POST'. That makes the if statement true and it enters the if tag.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad, i wanted to say, how does django know that my request is a post or a get request

Comment: @Jeppe does he know that my request is a POST or a GET request because of my html form method ?

Comment: @BidhanMajhi alright, i think i understand ! It’s related to my html form method ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to say exactly what happens in your case since we don't have your HTML but in general:

- When you create an HTML form,  you can specify a method as follows `<form method="POST"></form>` or `<form method="GET"></form>`. If you don't specify the default is GET.
- When you submit your form, it sends the data using an http request of the specified type. This is what Django is reading.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `request.method` simply represents the HTTP method that was used to access your view.  For example, your `register` function might be assigned a `url` configuration such as: `url(r'^register/', views.register)`, which maps an incoming HTTP request to your view.  If you have a web form with a 'Submit' button, it's likely the web application code is submitting an HTTP `POST` request to your web server.

Django automatically constructs the `request` object for you, so you can check in your view how the request was made against the web server.  For more info about what other things are included in the request, check the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/).